# Relational database vs object-relational database

Tags: mysql, postgresql

There's plenty of questions on SO about the differences between OO databases like MongoDB vs relational databases, but I can't find anything about the differences between a relational database like MySQL vs an object-relational database like PostgreSQL at a high level. I understand that these two particular databases have differing functionality respectively, but I don't really understand why something like MySQL that claims to be simply relational doesn't return the same formed data as an object-relational database like PostgreSQL. Some of what I read on other sources say it's what they return when queried that is different; is this true?

Comment: This a very general question. Why should different database be required to return the same formed data? Not sure of the context. For the most part SQL queries that don't deviate from the SQL standard will will return the same result.

Comment: Can you try to clarify the purpose of this differentiation? If you want comments on the accuracy of differences, be precise and quote references.

Comment: Who says that Postgres is an object relational database, and MySQL is not?  Is there any real meaning here?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen "PostgreSQL is a powerful, open source object-relational database system.." from the postgresl website. I want to know how that's different from just a relational database.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe this entry from DBA Stackexchange would be helpful:

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/77340/how-to-understand-object-relational

In particular, this answer: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/77344/111252

Essentially it describes built-in [inheritance features](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-inheritance.html) of Postgres that are outside of the SQL standard.  That seems to be the key difference.